# How to show pictures in libGDX?

Tags: java, libgdx, actor, scene2d

I am working on a game in which several pictures from directory are displayed on the screen. 
I'm using scene2d. 
But for some reason these pictures are not displayed on the screen.
Anyone can explain why? 
Here is my code:

```
public class Picture extends Actor {
    private Image img;
    public Picture(Image img) {
        this.img = img;
    }
}
```

And class of the game in which pictures should be drawn:

```
public class GameScreen extends Stage implements Screen {
     private FileHandle dirWithTextures;

public GameScreen() {
     super(new StretchViewport(1260.0f, 836.0f, new OrthographicCamera()));
     dirWithTextures = Gdx.files.internal("textures/");
}
public void buildStage() {
    ArrayList<Picture> pictureList = new ArrayList<Picture>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        pictureList.add(new Picture(new Image(newTexture(dirWithTextures.list()[i]))));
    }
    Collections.shuffle(pictureList);

    for (Picture p: pictureList) {
        p.setPosition(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2, Align.center);
        addActor(p);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please write a comment next time or edit your question instead of editing my answer. And what you mean on "I don't think" have you tried my code first? Actor has empty draw(..) method, so if you won't override it, it won't  be drawn.

Answer (score 1):

You are not overriding draw() method of Actor, so Picture draws nothing.

Override like this:

```
public class Picture extends Actor {
     private Image img;
     public Picture(Image img) {
         this.img = img;
     }
     @Overrine 
     public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha){
         image.draw(batch, parentAlpha);
     }
}
```

Actor draw method:

```
public void draw (Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `Picture` class is an `Actor` having `Drawable` part as in data member(`Image`).

Why you're not using `Image` instead of (Actor + Drawable).

> Image is an Actor that can be drawn.

```
public class Picture extends Image {

      // Any additional data members
}
```

For stage it's better to use association relationship instead of inheritance here.

```
public class GameScreen implements Screen {
    private FileHandle dirWithTextures;
    private Stage stage;

  public GameScreen() {

      stage= new Stage(new StretchViewport(1260.0f, 836.0f, new OrthographicCamera()));
      dirWithTextures = Gdx.files.internal("textures/");
      buildStage();
  }

  public void buildStage() {
      ArrayList<Picture> pictureList = new ArrayList<Picture>();

      for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
          pictureList.add(new Picture(new Texture(dirWithTextures.list()[i])));
      }
      Collections.shuffle(pictureList);

      for (Picture p: pictureList) {
         p.setPosition(100, 200, Align.center);  // < -- set Position according to your requirement.
         stage.addActor(p);
      }
  }

  @Override
  public void render(float delta) {

       Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0,0,0,1);
       Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

       stage.draw();
       stage.act();
  }

  // implement rest of method of Screen interface
}
```